# APIARY Mock JSON Data for multiple Single Object

Tags: json, apiary.io, apiary

In my apiary, I have defined the following to retrieve one id when id is passed to
A single Note object with all its details

```
{ "id": 2, "title": "Pick-up posters from post-office" }
```

http://private-22c1f-polpan.apiary-mock.com/notes/2

If I would like to pass another id by passing 3, how to define JSON entry in apiary?

```
{ "id": 2, "title": "Pick-up posters from post-office" }
{ "id": 3, "title": "third entry" }
```

However when I tried as

http://private-22c1f-polpan.apiary-mock.com/notes/3

it is not returning details for id 3.

How could I fix this?

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution to the problem? I have the same issue!

Comment: @MaRco85 I haven't found a solution for this.

Comment: Have a look at this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911765/apiary-io-multiple-responses-200-with-different-parameters/30914662?noredirect=1#comment49872583_30914662

Comment: @MaRco85 It means it will return only what is defined as first response?

Comment: See my answer below @user75ponic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from this question:

[Apiary.io - multiple responses (200) with different parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911765/apiary-io-multiple-responses-200-with-different-parameters)

It looks like Apiary Mock Server creates/generates only one URL for each resource and that URL parameters are not "tied up" with different responses.
They might actually plan to do it in the future:
https://github.com/apiaryio/api-blueprint/issues/58

So, at the moment, I believe you have a simple solution to achieve what you need:

Create different resources (one for each record), so each one will generate one URL.

```
## Note20 [/notes/20]

### Get notes20 [GET]

+ Response 200 (application/json)

        {
            "id" : 20,
            "name" : "note xxxx"
        } 

## Note21 [/notes/21]

### Get notes21 [GET]

+ Response 200 (application/json)

        {
            "id" : 21,
            "name" : "note yyyyy"
        }
```

Otherwise you can play with headers parameters, sent every time you call the URL, as explained in this link: http://support.apiary.io/knowledgebase/articles/117119-handling-multiple-actions-on-a-single-resource but I don't find it good.

I don't have other solutions at the moment.
Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

There [is a doc how to handle it](http://support.apiary.io/knowledgebase/articles/117119-handling-multiple-actions-on-a-single-resource); basically, you need to have separate resources for separate payloads, as there is currently no way to "bind" URL argument into payload.

Comment: Hi Almad, Can you please provide an example? I am struggling to find the right answer to implement this. Thank you!