# Apiary.io different responses without depending on status codes

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary.io

I was trying to create an API mock using [apiary.io](https://apiary.io/). A section of my current API blueprint looks like follows.

```
+ Request (application/json)

    {
        "key": "secret",
    }

+ Response 200 (application/json)

    {
        "decision_type" : 1,
    }

+ Response 202 (application/json)

    {
        "decision_type" : 2,
    }

+ Response 203 (application/json)

    {
        "decision_type" : 3,
    }
```

According to the API documentation provided to me, the ideal case should be such that the response status returned in all the three cases should be `200`. But since apiary uses status codes to differentiate between the responses, I am forced to use `202` and `203` status codes. Is there any way by which I could avoid this?

I thought of a functionality by which it would give different responses based on different parameters. But it seems like this functionality is still being implemented ([Apiary.io - multiple responses (200) with different parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911765/apiary-io-multiple-responses-200-with-different-parameters)).

Is there a way to denote the blueprint like the following?

```
+ Response 200 (application/json) type=1

    {
        "decision_type" : 1,
    }

+ Response 200 (application/json) type=2

    {
        "decision_type" : 2,
    }

+ Response 200 (application/json) type=3

    {
        "decision_type" : 3,
    }
```

And this `type` can be accessed as a header during `REST` calls.

I will be forced to turn down apiary and move to other applications to generate a mock which would mean a great deal of work as my API is really BIG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API mock will always give your the first response in your document. If you just want to use it for mock you try something thing like this:

```
## Get Decision type 1 [/?type=1]

### decision type [GET]


+ Response 200 (application/json) 

        {
            "decision_type" : 1,
        }

## Get Decision type 2 [/?type=2]

### decision type [GET]


+ Response 200 (application/json) 

        {
            "decision_type" : 2,
        }

## Get Decision type 3 [/?type=3]

### decision type [GET]


+ Response 200 (application/json) 

        {
            "decision_type" : 3,
        }
```